# Convert vector like c("x","y","z") to function(x , y, z){}

Tags: r, function, vector, arguments

How to convert vector like `c("x","y","z")` to  `function(x , y, z){}` in R?

I am looking for something like reverse function of `formalArgs()`.

Note that, I know about `as.function(alist(x=,y=,{}))` but I don't know how to insert `x=` and `y=` in it from a given vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically to get this to work you need to call

```
as.function(alist(x=, y=, z=, {}))`
```

which is equivalent to

```
as.function(alist(x=bquote(), y=bquote(), z=bquote(), {}))
```

The second form is nice because we have a set of named arguments to `alist`, which can provide programmatically using a list and `do.call`:

```
l <- list(x=bquote(), y=bquote(), z=bquote(), bquote({}))
as.function(do.call(alist, l))
# function (x, y, z) 
# {
# }
```

All that remains is to construct our list `l` programmatically from the list of variable names, which can be done with `setNames` and `replicate`:

```
vec <- c("x","y","z")
as.function(do.call(alist, c(setNames(replicate(length(vec), bquote(), F), vec),
                             bquote({}))))
# function (x, y, z) 
# {
# }
```

Answer (score 3):

The arguments are just a named list. The coercion to the internal pairlist is automatic.

```
#argument list
p<-c("x","y","z")
args<-vector("list",length(p))
for(i in seq(args)) args[[i]]<-substitute()
names(args)<-p

#set a default value for y for the sake of example
args$y<-2

#construct function
body<-quote(x+y+z)
f<-as.function(c(args,body))

#test it
f(1,z=3)
#[1] 6
```